# javascript strip tags working on my script

Tags: javascript, strip-tags, zeroclipboard

I am using [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/) to copy code from a generator which can then be pasted by the user. I can easily copy the code from the generator to the clipboard, however when I add the `.replace` command after `.innerHTML` it also copies the html tags `<p>` and `<span>`.
The HTML for the output of the generator is as shown below:

```
<div id="jj_yourcode_br" class="jj_yourcode">
    <p>border-radius: <span id="jj_radius">10</span>px; </p>
</div>
```

and the javascript that gets the text from the element and tried to replace the HTML tags with a blank value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath( 'http://joomjunk.co.uk/modules/mod_css3_gen/js/ZeroClipboard.swf' );
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();

    clip.setText( document.getElementById('jj_yourcode_br').innerHTML.replace(/<\S[^><]*>/g, '' );
    clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
</script>
```

What have I done wrong with the javascript code and how can I fix it so that it eliminates these tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a `)` there

```
clip.setText(document.getElementById('jj_yourcode_br').innerHTML.replace(/<\S[^><]*>/g, '' ));
```